# checking tool for spelling and javadoc validation

Tags: java, coding-style, documentation, javadoc, checkstyle

apologies if the question is a duplicate.

Actually I am looking for a automated checking tool to identify:

- the missing javadoc,
- incomplete javadoc or
- missing brief
- test and identify spelling or grammar mistakes in javadoc comments.

I know there are few tools available to do these things such as [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) and [open javadoc check](https://github.com/egonw/ojdcheck) etc. But I would need suggestions if there are any more tools available if yes, which one would be more suitable for my need.

Answer (score 0):

IDEs (Integrated Development Environments) commonly include spell-checking in javadocs and comments. I know that Eclipse definitely does ( http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ - pick IDE for java developers 150mb).

Also, you shouldn't have to apoligize for whether the question is a duplicate - your first resource should be to google, your second resource SO search, and your third resource the "Similar Questions" box you get while typing your title.

Comment: well I have done all three searches but sometimes the answer might be there but it may not popup with my search query, hence the 1st line. I am aware of spell check done by eclipse but I was wondering of there is a tool to perform missing checks and also grammar validations.

Comment: Hmm, I know that generally, grammar verification wouldn't go over very well - a variety of tones are used in documentation in different places. As for missing documentation, you could always go over the built site pages and check if anything's empty :)

Comment: sorry, I am looking for an automated tool I know I can check it manually but for 200-300 classes it wont be a good idea

Comment: I guess Checkstyle does that for you (and find even lots of other code *issues*).

Answer (score 0):

About spelling and grammar - do you do code reviews before people check their code in? How about checking the spelling and grammar then?

For the already existing classes - if you really need a better grammar check, you would either have to use a commercial tool or write a tool yourself (e.g. a python script that parses all javadocs and runs a spell and grammar checker on it)

Comment: Code review will indeed catch that sort of thing, but if I'm the one doing the code review, I don't want to put 1000 comments on the review about all the incorrect spelling and punctuation. It wastes a bunch of my time, and it wastes a bunch of the original author's time since they then have to go through one by one, fix them and commit again.